# parsing Xml for Java

Tags: java, xml, nodelist

There exists XML document like this:

```
<root>
    <a/>
    <a/>
    <a/>
    <b>
        <c/>
            <d/>
        <c/>
            <d/>
        <c/>
            <d/>
    </b>
</root>
```

Following code is using to get "a" NodeList:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = dBuilder.parse(xmlfile);
doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
NodeList aNodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("a");
```

But how in Java I can retrieve NodeList of "c"?
I tried to get nodes of "b" nodes but it have not results, getlength() = 0.

```
NodeList bNodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("b");
NodeList cNodes = bNodes.item(0).getChildNodes();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get them by `doc.getElementsByTagName("c")` like this.

```
NodeList cNodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("c");
for (int i = 0; i < cNodes.getLength(); ++i)
    System.out.println(cNodes.item(i));
```

output:

```
[c: null]
[c: null]
[c: null]
```

I can also retrieve NodeList of "b".

```
NodeList bNodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("b");
NodeList bChildren = bNodes.item(0).getChildNodes();
for (int i = 0; i < bChildren.getLength(); ++i)
    System.out.println(bChildren.item(i));
```

output:

```
[#text: 
        ]
[c: null]
[#text: 
            ]
[d: null]
[#text: 
        ]
[c: null]
[#text: 
            ]
[d: null]
[#text: 
        ]
[c: null]
[#text: 
            ]
[d: null]
[#text: 
    ]
```